# How to merge multiple filed which contain null value

Tags: neo4j, cypher

1.I'm trying to import JSON file and create a graph but value.replyto_user_id replyto_id contain null value,

```
CALL apoc.load.json("file:///tweets.json")
YIELD value
MERGE (t:Tweets
{
id: value.id,
created_at: value.created_at,
text: value.text,
user_id: value.user_id,
retweet_id: value.retweet_id,
retweet_user_id: value.retweet_user_id,
user_mentions: value.user_mentions,
replyto_id: value.replyto_id,
replyto_user_id: value.replyto_user_id
}
)
```

2.Erro message: Cannot merge node using null property value. Then I tired

```
CALL apoc.load.json("file:///tweets.json")
YIELD value 
with value where value.replyto_user_id and replyto_id  is not null
{
id: value.id,
created_at: value.created_at,
text: value.text,
user_id: value.user_id,
retweet_id: value.retweet_id,
retweet_user_id: value.retweet_user_id,
user_mentions: value.user_mentions,
replyto_id: value.replyto_id,
replyto_user_id: value.replyto_user_id
}
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you [MERGE](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/merge/) a node, you should only specify the properties that *uniquely identify* that node. That way, if the node already existed but some *non-identifying* properties have different values, the `MERGE` will not create a new node.

I will assume that in your data model the `id` property value uniquely identifies a `Tweet` node (renamed from `Tweets`, since each node represents just one tweet).

Also, I will assume that you want to set to the non-identifying properties only when a `Tweet` node is `first created`. To ensure that, the query below uses [ON CREATE](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/merge/#merge-merge-with-on-create).

```
CALL apoc.load.json("file:///tweets.json") YIELD value
MERGE (t:Tweet {id: value.id})
ON CREATE SET t += value{
  .created_at, .text, .user_id, .retweet_id, .retweet_user_id,
  .user_mentions, .replyto_id, .replyto_user_id}
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid duplications of tweets, you do not have to include all properties in the MERGE. Just the id that uniquely identifies the tweet.

```
MERGE (t:Tweets {id:value.id})
SET t.prop1= value.prop1,
        t.prop2= value.prop2
```

should do it, and you do not have to worry about nulls.

Make sure you have an index / constraint set on Tweets.id